# how to make a button:hover affect a lebel in java fx

Tags: css, javafx

i'm trying to make a label and a button connected using css in java fx but it is'nt working.

```
#B0{
    -fx-border-radius:10px;
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
#B0:hover{

    -fx-border-radius:10px;
    -fx-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -fx-background-color: green;

}
#B0:hover ~ #label{

    -fx-background-color: green;

}
```

the label isn't changing it's background color

Comment: _label and a button connected_ what do you mean by that? [mcve] please. Label might not support hover

Comment: @kleopatra the CSS is pretty clear about this: Apply the style to the node with the id `label`, if the sibling with the id `B0` is hovered; works in html, but not in javafx. Also I'm pretty sure `Label` does support hover, since this property is part of `Node`...

Comment: @fabian ahh .. yeah, you are right, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectors available in javafx are limited. Sibling selectors are not implemented. The only way of achieving something like this is to modify the label or the common parent to allow for a selector that is implemented in JavaFX in java code:

```
PseudoClass containsButtonHover = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("contains-button-hover");
Button button = ...

// apply pseudoclass to common parent iff button is hovered
button.hoverProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> button.getParent().pseudoClassStateChanged(containsButtonHover, newValue));
```

```css
#B0{
    -fx-border-radius:10px;
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
#B0:hover{

    -fx-border-radius:10px;
    -fx-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -fx-background-color: green;

}
*:contains-button-hover>#label {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```